# Query on SQL HA/DR

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2017, clustering, hadr

DC1: we have two DB servers (DB1 and DB2) on top of WSFC

DC2: 1 DB server (standalone DB machine).

I have configured SQL Always-On on DC1 from DB1 to DB2. Now I have to sync/replicate data from DC1-DB1-->DC2-DB3 or DC1-DB2-->DC2-DB3. Please advise how to achive this.

Customer is not ready to provide one more DB box on DC2, if i get one more DB machine on DC2, i can use Distributed SQL Always-on for sync from DC1 to DC2 on top of two WSFC's.

I am using MS SQL 2017 Ent edition.

Comment: Can you please validate, if you are able to add DC2-DB3 server into the same cluster of DC1-DB1,DB2?

Comment: Thinking about it and there some option.

1 - Use log shipping from your DC1 to DC2 (if you have access to your backup, that seems like the easiest solution to have a "warm" copy of your data on DC2. It will also be easy to configure and to manage)

2 - Add DC2.DB3 into the DC1 cluster and add DB3 as a node to your AG (Using multi-subnet cluster).
* If you go that way, make sure you configure the Quorum correctly so that you do not bring DC1 if DC2 is not available for example.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your inputs. 


As per my knowldge, to add DC2-DB3 on same cluster, quroum drive should be accessaible from DC1 to DC2 and vice-versa. And server should be in domain. Is this my understanding is correct? Currently both DC1 and Dc2 servers in workgroup not in domain.


Regading Log shiping, i think it's not possible to put secondary DB's in read only mode, it's in standby mode. As per buisness requirement, i have to mark seconadry node as read only to generate reports (only select operations).

Comment: @SridharG Are DC1 and DC2 domains/domain controllers? If so, how are they in a workgroup? If they're not, then have you already configured domain-less cluster for the AG on DB1 and DB2?

In any case, it seems like your simplest option would be to add DB3 as a secondary replica on your existing AG, depending on your latency, existing architecture etc. Can you provide more details to clarify?

Comment: Just a quick clarification. **DC1** is **Data Centre 1** and **DB1** is the name of the server and **not** the name of the database?

Comment: Hi HandyD
<In any case, it seems like your simplest option would be to add DB3 as a secondary replica on your existing AG>


As i said, DB1, DB2 are in DC1 (in WSFC), but DB3 is on DC2 and it's not part of DC1 WSFC. Will existing AG will allow to add DB3 as a secondary replica?


Hi John,

DC1 is Data Centre 1
DB1 is server name and in this server name of DB is DB1
DB2 is server name and in this server name of DB is DB2
DC2 is Data Centre 2
DB3 is server name and in this server name of DB is DB3